# Combinatorics permutation with letters and numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a valid name is of length 3 or more up until 100 (including 100)
A valid name also has to satisfy:

- It has at least one lower-case letter (a-z)
- At least one upper-case letter (A-Z)
- At least one digit (0-9)

But, there is a rule. The rule is that names with the exact same letters and digits are considered the same. So for example, the name "AaZ41" is the same as "a1Z4A" and "1aB" is the same as "1111BBBaaaa"
So in short, the order does not matter, and so is the number of repeated character ("1qZ" = "q1ZZ" but **not** equal to "1zqZ" as lower-cased z isn't there)

> How many **different** names are there?

My approach:

The reasonable thing to notice is that because we can have names that are more than 62 characters long ( because uppercase + lowercase + digits = 26+26+10 = 62)
Then by the pigeonhole principal, after we pass the 62'nd character we will use something that has already been used and thus not changing the actual name.

So we need each iteration take $i$ upper-cased letters, $j$ lower-cased letter and $k$ digits such that:
$$ i + j + k = 62$$

And thus I think it is:

$$ \sum_{i+j+k=3}^{i+j+k =62} \overbrace{\binom{26}{i}}^{\text{upper}} \overbrace{\cdot \binom{26}{j} }^{ \text{lower}}\cdot \overbrace{\binom{10}{k}}^{\text{digits}}$$

But how do I evaluate this (Answer should be a number, not a sum..)? and I am not sure if that is even close to the way of solving it..
I would appreciate your kind help! Thanks!

Comment: You can include (or not) each of `a-zA-Z0-9` in $2^{62}$ ways. Now you should exclude cases when no lower letters ($2^{36}$ ways), no digits ($2^{52}$ ways) and so on

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin so is it  $2^{62} - 2^{36} - 2^{36} - 2^{52}$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin if I remove all the passwords that does not contain: upper / lower / digit  and add (upper $\cap$ lower + upper $\cap$ digit + lower $\cap$ digit$ ) minus ( digit $\cap$ upper $\cap$ lower)  so then is the cardinality of digit $\cap$ lower $\cap$ upper ? is it 1 or 0 (I mean, what is the cardinality of the intersection of the groups of passwords which does not contain a digit / uppercase / lowercase) it should be the emptyset no?

Comment: So the cardinality is $1$ -- when we take nothing, and yes, you use the [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), but I'm not quite sure how to use it correctly, if I was, it was an answer, not a comment. )

Comment: And your sum, [computed in python](https://tio.run/##RY7LDsIgEEX3fAVLBqgRGq0LWfUzjIuqrU4rj1C68OuxGKObczI3mZkbXunhXX0IMWe0wcdEMfUxef@cyTewXXqQ1hRtrt5eSOdmMy@WtUzvJQL/eCxWWzkBHXykKEc5UXT/c5sQ/W25JsbZKXbu3jMldQNnrsVvVgrOABQHWh8NilFMR7PXQEJEl9j6V17QFYMsJUzFhKo052pbqBuxcqcL66Yk6y7k/AY) is $-1+2^{10}+2^{27}-2^{52}-2^{37}+2^{62}$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin well, as you checked in with python you did use the PIE - let $A$ be the set of names without an upper - $B$ without lower $C$ without a digit. so $|A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$.   we get: $|A \cap B| = 2^{10}$ is the set of names with digits, $|A \cap C| = 2^{26}$ is only with lower - etc.. we get $2^{62} - 2^{37} - 2^{52} + 2^{27} +  2^{10} - 1$ - the only thing I don't get is why it is $-1$ when the intersection of the three should yield a positive number.

Comment: This $1$ corresponds to the case when you take no lower letters, no upper letters and no digits into the password -- you can do it exactly $1$ ways -- it's the empty password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum is not that scary. First, it's not $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i+j+k=3}^{i+j+k=62}$, but $\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{26}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{26}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}}$ and can be rearranged as
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{26}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{26}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10} {26\choose i}{26\choose j}{10\choose k}&=
\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{26}{26\choose i}\right)\cdot
\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{26}{26\choose j}\right)\cdot
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}{10\choose k}\right)\\
&=\left(2^{26}-1\right)\cdot
\left(2^{26}-1\right)\cdot
\left(2^{10}-1\right),
\end{align*}$$
and actually you get the same result using the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).